# Crude oil contamination hazard

Tags: health, soil

I'm not sure if this is physics, biology or chemistry related so I will start here.
I'm from a city (Baku, Azerbaijan) where crude oil is known to be extracted since ancient times. Oil is no longer being produced within city limits however soil is still heavily contaminated in some parts of the city. 
Recently a major project has started to turn one of the most contaminated parts of the century old oilfield (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_City_(Baku) for more) into urban territory.
Developer promises that all contaminated soil is being removed and recultivated but I still have some doubts about it. I also don't trust official reports so would like to conduct my own investigation.
What is the health hazard of soil contamination? Are hydrocarbon vapors direct health hazard? Or may be it's radon that surfaces with oil? What and how to check? Would I be ok if I just check radioactive contamination with dosimeter/radiometer?

Edit:

You can ignore water contamination and direct contact with chemicals. I'm talking only about vapors during hot season.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Soil contamination or soil pollution is caused by the presence of xenobiotic (human-made) chemicals or other alteration in the natural soil environment. It is typically caused by industrial activity, agricultural chemicals, or improper disposal of waste. The most common chemicals involved are petroleum hydrocarbons, polynuclear aromatic hydrocarbons (such as naphthalene and benzo(a)pyrene), solvents, pesticides, lead, and other heavy metals. Contamination is correlated with the degree of industrialization and intensity of chemical usage.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_contamination

> The acute health effects of hydrocarbon mixtures are generally associated with exposure concentrations at thousands of ppm. However, the exposure concentration and exposure duration leading to the onset of acute health effects varies between individual hydrocarbons, and this may influence the effects of exposure to mixtures.Health effects associated with a single exposure to hydrocarbons are asphyxiation, narcosis (ie depression of the central nervous system; anaesthesia), cardiac arrest and aspiration. Of these, the first two are probably the most significant in the offshore context.

http://www.hse.gov.uk/offshore/notices/sn_04_04.htm

> In relation to the assessment of vapour risk,petroleum hydrocarbons and chlorinated hydrocarbons differ in their potential forvapour intrusion (VI) risks, primarily because petroleum hydrocarbons (PHCs) readily
>   biodegrade in the subsurface when sufficient oxygen is available(USEPA 2011,2012a). Hence while a number of aspects of this guidance are general and can beapplied to a range of volatile compounds, the guidance is intended to specificallyaddress PVI and should not be applied to sites contaminated with other compounds
>   including chlorinated hydrocarbons and landfill gas.

http://clu-in.org/download/issues/vi/CRCCARETechreport23-PetroleumhydrocarbonvapourintrusionassessmentAustralianguidance2.pdf

> Organic compounds can be a major pollution problem in groundwater. Their presence in water can create a hazard to public health and the environment. This page will focus on the BTEX's which makes up one of the main groups of soluble organic compounds that find their way into our soil and groundwater. One of the most common sources for BTEX-contamination of soil and groundwater are spills involving the release of petroleum products such as gasoline, diesel fuel and lubricating and heating oil from leaking oil tanks. Because of their polarity and very soluble characteristics, the organic chemicals (BTEX's) of petroleum products will be able to enter the soil and groundwater systems and cause serious pollution problems.

http://www.webapps.cee.vt.edu/ewr/environmental/teach/gwprimer/btex/btex.html

[image]

> Petroleum vapours at percentage concentrations are flammable, potentially explosive
>   and acutely toxic; lower explosive limits (LEL) for many volatile hydrocarbons are in the
>   low percentage range. Petroleum vapours are denser than air. Some components of
>   petroleum vapour are also chronically toxic at trace concentrations and as such are also
>   considered under the heading VOCs [volatile organic compounds ].

http://www.epa.nsw.gov.au/resources/clm/120932GroundGas.pdf

This document contains site investigation details which describes how to find traces of compounds in soil and water.
.

Comment: I appreciate the collection of information from many different sites. I think this would be most helpful to the author if you synthesized the information a little more, presented some main takeaway points? Also, I noticed you have copy-pasted a number of paragraphs directly from the different links. While it's good you show your sources, you might want to look at the guidelines on referencing and see if you can make these quotes conform better to standards: http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing. In particular, I think you could make it clear which parts are direct quotes.

Comment: @A.Kennard  As the author asked multiple questions I thought it will be nice if I give him direct copies from those links and those sentences seems fine to me, and mostly I thought when he visit those pages he can identify those sentences there and continue reading. It is so much appreciable that you spend some time to guide me through SE. Thanks for your valuable advice, I'll try to improve.

Comment: Thanks Jvrek! It seems like it shouldn't be a cause to cancer or similar nasty stuff unless really high concentrations. I've been living in close proximity to the area and haven't noticed any immediate and obvious health problems. I'm just total noob on the subject therefore hesitate a lot.